# I make some changes in css of react-nice-ticker package but when i deploy code then all my changes override

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, sass, react-redux

this is my style.css

```
.styles_ticker__8iZE9 {
    background-color: rgb(56, 55, 63);
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #26A69A;
    
}
.styles_tickerItemFinancial__3uuXj:hover {
    background-color: rgb(56, 55, 63);
    cursor: pointer;

}
.newsticker{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;

}

a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.styles_newsticker__2xlP7 {
    min-width: 27%;
    padding: 0.6rem;
    color: #26A69A;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #26A69A;

}
.styles_newsticker__2xlP7:hover {
    background-color: rgb(56, 55, 63);
}

.styles_title__24Ef9:hover , .styles_newsticker__2xlP7:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.styles_tickerItem__1yblE:after {
    background: #26A69A;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: -1px;
    width: 2px;
}

.styles_meta__2enVD {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

this is my .js file
this is my react component where I implement a nice react ticker package.

```
import Ticker, { FinancialTicker, NewsTicker } from 'nice-react-ticker';
import axios from 'axios'
import './TickerList.style.css'
    render() {
        return (
          <div>      
              <Ticker style={{paddingBottom :"50px"}}>
                 {
                 this.state.tickerData.map(buc => (
                   <FinancialTicker id={buc.id} change={true} symbol={buc[1]} lastPrice={buc[3]} percentage={buc[2]} />
                  ))
                }
              </Ticker>   
          </div>

        )
    }
}
```

when I deploy my code on AWS the pre-styling of the package override my styling
but in local everything works fine (my changes not override by pre-styling)
how can I stopped pre-styling to override my local style

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your change only apply on local, when you deploy to AWS it will install new package as you haven't edit it yet, your local change won't affect.

Take a look at [Patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package). It will help you fix a bug in your dependencies automatically after `npm install`. Or simply create a bash script that will regex and replace the file you want and put it to `postinstall` of scripts in package.json.